# Data object property is read only

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

I know that sometimes when the frontend receives data from mongoose, it is as a read-only document. However, when I go the error today: TypeError: "contracts" is read-only, my first thought was this and so I assigned a new variable to the data, tried running a map on the data (data.map(x => x)), tried assigning the data with a spread operator, but I keep getting the same error, so I really dont know what I'm missing.

Heres the data that comes in, as logged in the console:

```
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { _id: "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4", fullName: "Johnny Cochrane", contracts: {…} }
​​
_id: "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4"
​​
contracts: Object { type: "Quarterly", hours: 120 }
​​
fullName: "Johnny Cochrane"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
1: Object { _id: "6217c1b73fe12d6b4ec3550e", fullName: "Sheila Thompson", contracts: {…} }
```

And here is where I'm assigning new fields thats throwing the error:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(data) {

            let dataArr = [...data]
        
            const contractsByMonth = (type, hours) => {
                if (type === "Quarterly") {
                let monthHours = hours / 3
                return +(Math.round(monthHours + "e+2")  + "e-2");
            }     
            }

            dataArr.map(i => {
                let monthly = contractsByMonth(i.contracts.type, i.contracts.hours)
                i.contracts = {type: i.contracts.type, monthHours: monthly, total: i.contracts.hours  } 

...
}, [data])
```

So I know the data is there, it is not in a string that needs to be parsed, and even trying to reassign it is not seeming to work. Appreciate any thoughts anyone has. Shouldnt be the issue, but I'm using RTK Query to get the data, but I use it all the time without this issue, my guess is that its treating the data as the original mongoose returned document.

**EDIT**

Adding more of the components code:

```
const HoursGraph = () => {
 const {id} = useAuth()
 const userId = id

...

const  [pullData, {data}]  = useGetSnapshotMutation({userId, isStart, isEnd}) 
// RTK Query mutation which pulls the data- its an aggregation and I pass criteria through the body, but I've done this plenty without issue

...
useEffect(() => {
 ...
if (index === 0) {
            start = new Date(end).setDate(1)
        } else if (index === 1) {
            const startMth = currentMth - 1
            console.log(currentMth, startMth)
            start = new Date(new Date(new Date(end).setMonth(startMth, 1)).setHours(0, 0, 0)).toISOString()
        } else if (index === 2) {
            const startMth = currentMth -2
            console.log(currentMth, startMth)
            start = new Date(new Date(new Date(end).setMonth(startMth, 1)).setHours(0, 0, 0)).toISOString()
        }
        setIsStart(start)
        setIsEnd(end)
}, [])

 useEffect(() => {
        if(isStart && isEnd && userId) {
            pullData({userId, isStart, isEnd})
        }
    }, [isStart, isEnd, userId])
    
    console.log("snapshot data: ", data) //this logs the data referenced above

 useEffect(() => {
        if(data) {

            let dataArr = [...data]
        
            const contractsByMonth = (type, hours) => {
                if (type === "Quarterly") {
                let monthHours = hours / 3
                return +(Math.round(monthHours + "e+2")  + "e-2");
            }     
            }

            dataArr.map(i => {
                let monthly = contractsByMonth(i.contracts.type, i.contracts.hours)
                i.contracts = {type: i.contracts.type, monthHours: monthly, total: i.contracts.hours  } //This throws the error

                let colors
                let sum

                let qtrSum = i.hours.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.count + curr.count)
                console.log("sum: ", qtrSum)
                const color= ['#73E078', '#26A69A', '#26C6DA', '#29B6F6']
                
                i.hours = i.hours.map(x => {return ( {date: x.date, count: x.count, month: monthly } )})
                i[colors] = color
                i[sum] = qtrSum
                })
                console.log(data)
...
}, [data])
```

Comment: Which line of code causes the error?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice dataArr.map- assigning to i.contracts

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that recreates the error? More complete code will help a lot.

Comment: Since when I saw the issue before it was the data response from Mongoose that caused it, I wasn't sure how to set up a code sandbox with all of the pieces. I'll work on that. In the meantime I'll add more of the code to the question

Comment: You are using map wrong. You have to return a new object instead of assigning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of assigning to i.contracts, which appears to be read-only, try

```
dataArr.map((i) => {
  const monthly = /*yourt code here*/
  const contracts = {...i.contracts, monthHours: monthly, total: i.contracts.hours} //this obviously has a different type than the original i.contracts, which is an issue you will still have to deal with
  return {...i, contracts};
})
```

This issue is probably that the contracts you're trying to mutate on i is typed as read-only (and you're trying to mutate it to a different type). RTK Query uses immer under the hood, which might protect you from the consequences of rewriting that property if you make the edit in the `transformResponse` field of your endpoint. It might not let you change the type in the process though.

Comment: Be sure to assign the result of `map()` to a variable.

Comment: I was assuming that part was in the part they left off with ..., but that's a good point--they're solely mutating it in the map and not doing anything with that.

Comment: I mean specifically in your answer. Something like `let newData = dataArr.map(...)` would make it more complete.

Comment: In the OP, this couldn't be in the `...` because it has to be with the `map()` call.

Comment: With any luck they moved the transformation to transformResponse.